# How to restrict AWS lambda access to only one role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, amazon-iam

I have created one lambda. I need to provide access to only one role that is created for this lambda i.e. only this role should have the invoke access. There may be other roles in account which may have invoke access on all lambdas but I want to restrict those roles not to access my lambda.
Can anyone please suggest a way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: I'd try a Resource Policy with an explicit Deny and the [NotPrincipal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html) condition that references your role.

Comment: @Maurice see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html, specifically note "You can only update resource-based policies for Lambda resources within the scope of the AddPermission and AddLayerVersionPermission API actions. Currently, you can't author policies for your Lambda resources in JSON, or use conditions that don't map to parameters for those actions."  Hence, custom resource policies are of limited use for lambda.

Comment: For those stumbling their way to this question, the use of AWS Organizations Service Control Policies (SCPs) seem to be the only practical answer at present...

Answer (score 1):

A resource-based policy attached to a lambda function will work as Maurice commented.

Below is the sample policy. The action specified in the policy statement is explicitly denied to all principals except for the one specified. Only lambda_role is allowed to invoke testfunction lambda using the below resource-based policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "0001",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::659266464590:role/service-role/lambda_role"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:659266464590:function:testfunction"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If someone again creates another policy for other role which will allow the invoke access to that role, in that case will it override the above policy ?

Comment: No, an explicit Deny always takes precedence.

Comment: How have you attached this resource based policy to the Lambda? I have found only add-permission action to be registered in the lambda API

Comment: there are two roles 1. which is specific to lambda which it assumes while invoke 2. I need to create another role , only this role can be assumed by allowed user and invoke lambda. Means i will create one role and provide to users , they can assume this role and can invoke lambda , no other user or role apart from this should access the lambda . How we can do this   @dossani

Comment: I am not able to add notPrincipal from AWS-UI, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The question specifically explains that there could be multiple roles with lambda:InvokeFunction in the same account. It's about how to create a role that doesn't have lambda:InvokeFunction permission.

By default, any [IAM principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html) in the account that has invoke permission to our specific Lambda ARN resource or to all Lambda functions in the account would be able to invoke the function.

Lambda [resource based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html) is also not the answer here, as it only has **Allow** effect and **Deny** effect is not supported in the policy.

If we want to overwrite/limit the user/role permissions in general in an account, the only applicable option here is [organizational policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies.html).